# I/flutter (29011): NoSuchMethodError: The method 'insert' was called on null. SQFLITE flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, sqflite

I am calling the database helper class from ui when I got data from api and that data I have to dump in database to use it offline in the application. I am getting this error. Where am I getting this error and why database is not initialized and allowing me to perform actions on it.

Error:

```
I/flutter ( 5420): NoSuchMethodError: The method 'insert' was called on null.
I/flutter ( 5420): Receiver: null
I/flutter ( 5420): Tried calling: insert("Deliveries", _LinkedHashMap len:6, conflictAlgorithm: Instance of 'ConflictAlgorithm')
E/flutter ( 5420): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method 'query' was called on null.
E/flutter ( 5420): Receiver: null
E/flutter ( 5420): Tried calling: query("Deliveries")
E/flutter ( 5420): #0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:53:5)
E/flutter ( 5420): #1      TodoHelper.getAllTask (package:delivery_app_odoo_flutter/utils/db_todays_deliveries_model.dart:110:55)
E/flutter ( 5420): #2      _TodayDeliveriesState.inertInDb (package:delivery_app_odoo_flutter/ui/deliveries_page/today_deliveries_page.dart:49:22)
E/flutter ( 5420): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 5420): #3      SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1102:15)
E/flutter ( 5420): #4      SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1049:9)
E/flutter ( 5420): #5      SchedulerBinding._handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:957:5)
E/flutter ( 5420): #6      _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1126:13)
E/flutter ( 5420): #7      _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1023:19)
E/flutter ( 5420): #8      _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:925:7)
E/flutter ( 5420): #9      _invoke (dart:ui/hooks.dart:259:10)
E/flutter ( 5420): #10     _drawFrame (dart:ui/hooks.dart:217:3)
E/flutter ( 5420):
```

**Model:**

The conversion logic is correct for the allitems in toMap method?. Because we have to convert it into string for storing into local database.

```
class TodayDeliveriesModel extends Equatable{
  String address;
  String CustomerName;
  String orderNumber;
  String total;
  List<ItemsModel> allItems;
  bool pending;

  TodayDeliveriesModel({this.address, this.CustomerName,this.orderNumber, this.allItems, this.total, this.pending});

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap(){
    return {
      Column_address : this.address,
      Column_CustomerName:this.CustomerName,
      Column_orderNumber:this.orderNumber,
      Column_total:this.total,
      Column_allItems:this.allItems?.map((e) =>
      e == null ? null : ItemsModel(quantity: e.quantity,name: e.name))
          ?.toList(),
      Column_pending:this.pending
    };
  }


  @override
  List<TodayDeliveriesModel> get props => deliveriesList;
}
```

**Calling from UI (stateful widget):**

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    TodoHelper.dba.initDatabase();
    todayDeliveries=TodayDeliveriesModel();
    listProp = todayDeliveries.props;
//    todoHelper=TodoHelper();
    insertDataInDB();
  }

  insertDataInDB()async{
    await TodoHelper.dba.insertTask(listProp);
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback(getFromDb);
  }

  void getFromDb(Duration timeStamp) async{
    await TodoHelper.dba.getAllTask().then((val){
      setState(() {
        val.forEach((v){
          dbList.add(v);
        });
      });
    });
  }
```

**Database helper class:**

```
  class TodoHelper{
  Database _db;

  TodoHelper._();

  static final TodoHelper dba = TodoHelper._();


  Future<Database> get database async {
    if (_db != null) return _db;
    // if _database is null we instantiate it
    _db = await initDatabase();
    return _db;
  }


  Future initDatabase() async{
    return await openDatabase(
        join(await getDatabasesPath(), "test.db"),
        onCreate: (db, version)async{
//          return _createDb(db);
          await db.execute("CREATE TABLE $tableName($Column_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, $Column_address TEXT, $Column_CustomerName TEXT, $Column_orderNumber TEXT, $Column_total TEXT,$Column_allItems TEXT,$Column_pending TEXT)");
        },
        version: 1
    );
  }

  Future<void> insertTask(List<TodayDeliveriesModel> task) async{
    final Database = await _db;
    try{
      task.forEach((val){
        Database.insert(tableName, val.toMap(), conflictAlgorithm: ConflictAlgorithm.replace);
      });

    }catch(_){
      print(_);
    }
  }


  Future<List<TodayDeliveriesModel>> getAllTask () async{
    final List<Map<String, dynamic>> tasks = await _db.query(tableName);

    return List.generate(tasks.length, (i){
      return TodayDeliveriesModel(address: tasks[i][Column_address],total: tasks[i][Column_total],allItems: tasks[i][Column_allItems],
          CustomerName:tasks[i][Column_CustomerName] ,orderNumber: tasks[i][Column_orderNumber],pending: tasks[i][Column_pending] );
    });
  }


}
```

Comment: Do check that db object inside the insertTask and getAllTask method of your Database Helper class is not null

Comment: Did i call the database helper in correct way in the ui code?

Answer (score 0):

`initDatabase()` is `async` but in `ToDoHelper` it isn't being waited for. The issue you have here is that `initDatabase()` is in the constructor which cannot be `async` or use `await`. I have a similar class to handle my apps db which waits for the DB to be required, then either opens the database and saves it to a `_db` variable or returns the `_db` variable if the database has previously been opened. This works because it ensures the correct futures have returned before trying to access the database.

If you remove `initDatabase()` from the constructor and replace `Database db;` with the following private variable and async getter, the database should work as expected.

```
  static Database _db;

  // If there is no database in place then initialise one
  Future<Database> get db async {
    if (_db != null) {
      return _db;
    }

    // Initialise db
    _db = await initDatabase();
    return _db;
  }
```

You'll also to make sure you always do `await db` instead of just `db`. So in the above example the code around `db.insert(...)` could become

```dart
final database = await db;
task.forEach((val){
  database.insert(tableName, val.toMap(), conflictAlgorithm: ConflictAlgorithm.replace);
});
```

Comment: I updated my database helper class and calling from ui but still getting same error. You can now check the latest code (i edited my post)

Comment: Thanks for trying out my answer! There are some syntax errors in your updated post in `insertTask`. The first line should be `final database = await database;` not `final Database = await _db;` and then `Database.insert(` should be `database.insert(`.

Comment: final dtbase = await db;
now i am using this line in my code. i make instance of database with name db

Comment: If you are using `dtbase = await db;` then your insert statement should be `dtbase.insert`

Comment: is my model ok?